# Flask: is it possible to instruct flask to *NOT* process portions of a template?

Tags: angularjs, python-3.x, flask, jinja2

I am trying to use both flask and angular.js. While rendering a page with flask, I tried to add some angular js and the two templating methods (tags) clash.

I want something like:

```
<div>
    {{ flaskReplacesThis }}
</div>
<div>
    {%?! Ignore this, flask! %?}
    {{ angularReplacesThis }}
    {%?! endIgnore %?}
</div>
```

Is it:

- a bad idea all round, and I should abandon hope, or
- should I roll my own solution (if so, how?).

I've tried googling and haven't seen anything I can fully understand / make use of.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `raw` block. Anything inside it won't be processed as jinja2 syntax.

```
<div>
    {{ flaskReplacesThis }}
</div>
<div>
    {% raw %}
    {{ angularReplacesThis }}
    {% endraw %}
</div>
```

Here is the [documentation link](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping) for it.

Comment: thank you!! :-) right now my angular replacing is broken though, lol. But I'm pretty sure it's something I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 3):

It is usually not recommended to mix server side templating (jinja2) and client side templating (angular) together but it is possible. You could try using the `$interpolateProvider` feature of angularjs which lets you define a custom set of delimiters. Since jinja2 uses `{{` and `}}` as delimiters as well, may be you could tell angular to use something different, say `[[` and `]]`

```
<script>
var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});
 .......
```

See [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/%24interpolateProvider) for the official documentation

Comment: ooh... that's nifty too. thank you! yeah I had a feeling that this was a bad idea all round but... I guess this is my way of learning 2 or 3 things simultaneously.

Comment: no problem. I definitely recommend using different delimiters to ensure there is no confusion later on specially few months down the road when you are trying to debug the code

Comment: Erm, there's nothing wrong with mixing server- and client-side templates. Jinja2 simply outputs an HTML file that Angular then passes over. In fact it's terribly useful for everything from extremely simple cache-busting to Jinja2 macros to...lots of stuff.